# Handling Boolean filter in angular 5 options fields?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, angular5

**HTML**

```
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
```

The above is the html template, i want to send the json response shown below, except when a particular option is selected, then only that value should be true.

**JSON**

```
 {
     one    : false,
     two    : false,
     three  : false,
     four   : false
 }
```

*For Example* -
If `one` is selected then json response should be like -

```
  {
     one    : true,
     two    : false,
     three  : false,
     four   : false
  }
```

How do i handle this in angular 5, is there any inbuilt function for this? or is there a better way to add a filter?

Comment: what should happen to json after selecting one and then selecting two, it should reset ??

Comment: It is single option, the function is called only on submit.

Comment: if it is one time, are you looking for something like this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sr6nzh?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Load your `options` from an array of objects and use two-way data binding on your `select` element, I.e.:

```
let options = [
    {
        value: 'one',
        optionName: 'One'
    },
    {
        value: 'two',
        optionName: 'Two'
    },
    {
        value: 'three',
        optionName: 'Three'
    }
]

let selectedOption = 'two'
```

---

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption ">
...
```

Then iterate over your options to build the response:

`console.log(options.map(x => x.value).map(x => { return {[x]: x === selectedOption ? true : false}}))`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
arrList = {
     one    : false,
     two    : false,
     three  : false,
     four   : false
 }
  options =["One","Two","Three","Four"]

  onOptionsSelected(e) {
    let result:any[] =[];
    result = this.arrList;
    result[this.options[e-1].toLowerCase()] = true
    console.log(result);
  }
```

code sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sr6nzh?file=app/app.component.ts